# AngularJS HTTP Interceptors

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if `HTTP Interceptors` in AngularJS cause a performance hit?

I want to intercept `requests` and prepend the absolute URL:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.url = 'http://localhost:9060/' + config.url;
            }
        };
     });

}]);
```

Comment: That particular interceptor wouldn't cause any substantial performance problems. If you're still worried, just use performance.now() to measure the time it takes to make the call with and without the interceptor. If you test it against a real backend, be sure to take enough sample measurements. Otherwise you could measure against a mocked http backend by utilizing the ngMockE2E module (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you do something crazy and time-consuming within your interceptor, the actual invocation of the interceptor will be absolutely negligible in your application as compared to anything else.